# Add new to xml file every time new content appears on the page

Tags: c#, xml

That's how I want all my news on xml-file. It must be such that as soon as you create a news, it must add to the .xml file.

Right now it comes with this error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have checked news content and there are over 160 posts in total.

Here's how I've shared my sitemap.xml into:

Sitemap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset>
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

<url>
  <loc>https://www.xxxxxx.com/</loc>
  <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
</url>
<new>
  <url>
    <loc></loc>
    <lastmod></lastmod>
    <changefreq></changefreq>
  </url>
</new>
</urlset>
```

Helpers to XML method:

```
using (var DB = new DBEntitiesDatabase())
        {
            var urlxml = "http://localhost:54775/sitemap.xml";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(urlxml);
            var newlist = DB.New.OrderBy(i => i.NewId).ToList();
            foreach (var item in newlist)
            {
                XElement add = doc.Element("new");
                add.Add(new XElement("url",
                    new XElement("Loc", "https://www.xxxxx.com/news/" + item.url + "/" + item.NewId),
                    new XElement("lastmod", item.opretDato),
                    new XElement("changefreq", "daily")));
            }
            doc.Save(urlxml);
        }
```

It tells me that add.Add is wrong `add.Add(new XElement("url",`

[Img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRGtd.png)

Comment: Is there any specific error/exception code?

Comment: @ManojKumarRai i have add img now.

Comment: i have fix its now with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875131/c-sharp-adding-data-to-xml-file